# What are the difference between SLED and RHEL WorkStation?

Tags: rhel, desktop, suse

What are the difference between SLED and RHEL WorkStation?
What are the advantages over community supported distros?

Answer (score 1):

> What are the difference between SLED and RHEL WorkStation?

As I understand it they are mostly related to configuration (e.g. SuSE has YaST, while RHEL has the `system-config-*`) tools.

> What are the advantages over community supported distros?

- You have a company that can provide you support (rather than needing to rely on mailing lists, forums etc...) should you need it.
- Some proprietary software (e.g. scientific/engineering tools) is certified for those distros; while it might work on other systems, you lose support.
- You can buy hardware (e.g. workstations, servers, storage systems...) that is certified to work well with RHEL/SLED/...
- Long support cycles (e.g. Red Hat has [a quite complex system](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata) for lifecycles; RHEL 7 has support until 2027).

While for a personal desktop running mostly open-source software they are not really relevant, for a business/corporate/research/science application, where downtime might cost lots of money, those matter.

Answer (score 0):

One important difference of SLED/RHEL -vs- public distros is that SLED/RHEL have paid support that is available.  I find that for many companies this fact is VERY important.